# Get TinyMCE instance by class

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, tinymce

I have a form with multiple TinyMCE instance.
I created the TextArea controls dynamically using a Repeater control - They all have the same ID,but I gave each one a different class. 
I assigned each of the TextArea controls a TinyMCE instance using the
editor_selector :   option in the  TinyMCE  Init function.

```
tinyMCE.init({ mode : 'textareas',theme : 'simple',editor_selector : 'upperBlock',directionality : 'rtl'});  tinyMCE.init({ mode : 'textareas',theme : 'simple',editor_selector : 'middleBlock',directionality : 'rtl'});
```

I want to refer to a specific TinyMCE instance in a JS function and get its content.
In the case when each TextArea control has a different id that could by done by using :

```
tinyMCE.get('IdOfYourTextBoxWithTheTinyMCEContent').getContent()
```

Is there a way to **get ref to a specific TinyMCE instance content by the class assigned to it** in the editor_selector option of the  TinyMCE  Init function ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi unfortunately  no answer yet gave an answer to my question.Is there a syntax an api function to get specific TinyMCE instance content by the class assigned to it. Do you wont me to accept an answer that do not give a solution ??? (By doing so I will  mislead other readers)

Comment: no, not specifally this question, but you've got some others going on :)

Comment: You are welcome to read my questions history and the answers. Only  after you do that you can judge if there was a good answer to a question of mine that I left with no  appropriate response.If you find one or more please let me know and I will fix it(It is not enough to refer only to the rate check the content)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can't be done with native TinyMCE methods. You have to loop for yourself, like e.g. (untested)

```
for (edId in tinymce.editors) {
        if (tinymce.editors[edId].settings.editor_selector == 'upperBlock') {
        // editor found - do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your good answer :) There is only one problem I have some how for a each editor there are 2 different edIds so the if condtion is true twice : The function I used to check Func() {
    alert("Inside Func  function ");  
    var i = 1;
    for (edId in tinymce.editors) {
        alert("edId  : " + edId);
        if (tinymce.editors[edId].settings.editor_selector == 'upperBlock') {
            alert("index :  " + i );
        }
        i++;
    } 
}   I have created only 3 TextArea control and 3 TinyMCE instances and only one has upperBlock value

Comment: You're welcome. Did you set the setting `mode` to `specific_textareas` as mentioned in the doku? http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:editor_selector

Comment: Thank you I did that . I still  get 2 values for each instance for example for the first I get- edId: ctl00_MainContent_EditorialTextTextAreasUC_rptTextAreas_ctl01_txtArea and  edId  : 0 .     For the second  instance I get - edId  : ctl00_MainContent_EditorialTextTextAreasUC_rptTextAreas_ctl02_txtArea and edId  : 1  etc

Comment: It sounds like there are more TinyMCE instances on the page as there should be. What echos `tinymce.editors.length`?

Comment: 3 and that the number of instances I created dynamically.For some reason for each instance 2 different edId val are created.I added a break command in the 'If block' to solve the problem ,but  I still want to know why that happens .        P.S  can you write me please where at TinyMCE documentation I can find the methods and properties I can apply to tinymce.editors  collection .    Thanks

Comment: Good question - since they updated their homepage I am missing some things. It's supposed to be linked here: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3:namespace.tinymce . But it's missing for any reason....

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong. It is not allowed in HTML to have more elements with the same ID. Give them the same class and diffirent IDs.

Comment: not necessarily: if he uses an asp-textbox the ids will get a scope-prefix and therefore may be unique on the page ...

Comment: if this answer solved your problem, you should accept the answer as solution!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using a Repeater control .In the ItemTemplate element I wrote <asp:TextBox ID="txtArea" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" >   when the control is rendered in the client side each TextBox gets its own client side id. I use the control in a Content page (of a MasterPage). I gave each TextBox a different class cause it it easier to locate it using JQuery selector in some JS functions I have(No need to pass the generated client id of the control to the function and unlike the id the class value is never changed when the page is created)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the editor by class, you have to set this properties first to the editor.

```
tinymceOptions: {
                  mode: 'specific_textareas',
                  editor_selector: "yourClassName"
                }
```

then, your textarea would be like:

```
<textarea class="yourClassName"></textarea>
```

and then, you can iterate between all the editors you have like

```
    tinymce.editors.forEach(function(editor) {
        if (editor.settings.editor_selector === 'yourClassName') {
        // do what you want!
    }
});
```